# How to create Datastore Composite Indexes with just Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to see if it's viable to just use Cloud Functions to interact with Datastore.

Is there a way to create Composite Indexes (*like index.yaml*) with just Cloud Functions? So only Cloud Functions code, and no App Engine code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only *create* Composite Index definitions via the command line tools (`gcloud datastore create-indexes`). This is an administrative function and shouldn't be a regular part of your application. You can use the in-browser 'Cloud Shell' in the Cloud Console to perform this once off step.

Once they are created, any Cloud Datastore entity written by your Cloud Functions code will be added to the composite index.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I'm still debating whether to use Cloud Functions or App Engine for my API. Is there anything Datastore related that Cloud Functions can't do that App Engine can? Thanks in advance! :)